# Way to check if type is an enum

Tags: c++, templates

How to check (without Boost or other nonstandard lib) if type passed to template is an enum type?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/type_traits/is_enum.hpp,

If this evaluates to `true`:

```
::boost::type_traits::ice_or<
           ::boost::is_arithmetic<T>::value
         , ::boost::is_reference<T>::value
         , ::boost::is_function<T>::value
         , is_class_or_union<T>::value
         , is_array<T>::value
      >::value
```

Then this base template is selected:

```
// Don't evaluate convertibility to int_convertible unless the type
// is non-arithmetic. This suppresses warnings with GCC.
template <bool is_typename_arithmetic_or_reference = true>
struct is_enum_helper
{
    template <typename T> struct type
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = false);
    };
};
```

Otherwise check if it's convertible to `int`:

```
template <>
struct is_enum_helper<false>
{
    template <typename T> struct type
       : ::boost::is_convertible<typename boost::add_reference<T>::type,::boost::detail::int_convertible>
    {
    };
};
```

If you want to do it as well as Boost, you'll have to define all those other traits. `<type_traits>` is like that.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html

I appreciate you want total portability and not to use boost.  If you find that impractical, you might still prefer to use a simple ifdef and the following:
MSDN has a similar facility on the front page of google results for `c++ is_enum`.
On recent GNU compilers, try your luck with `using std::tr1::is_enum;`

Even if you don't want to use boost, you could examine it for the technique used in determination.  Looks complex enough to be exclusion of all other possibilities :-/.

Comment: Actually, is_enum should be used with care. Some compilers don't support it correctly. See the latest version of boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html

Comment: @Cătălin: "broken under Borland C++ Builder 5, and for the Metrowerks compiler prior to version 8" isn't likely to bother too many people (poor old Borland).

Comment: @A-ha: to do it without Boost, open the Boost source and copy-paste. They have a habit of thinking hard and reviewing thoroughly, you probably won't find a better implementation.

Comment: @Tony: You're right. However, I still see Visual Studio 6 required in some projects, so why not MW 8 or BC 5? About the same generation :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter it's not about finding better implementation. I want to learn how it is done. That's all.